# Apply variable value to Pom.xml before mvn deploy

Tags: android, maven, gradle, pom.xml, aar

How would I apply values to variables before deploying the POM and the aar it creates to the repo?

I'm uploading it as an azure artifact. I have 3 mvn deploy tasks passing the 3 different variable values using -Dvariable="something" command. The POM that it uploads still has the the variable and not the value in it. So apps trying to consume my AAR in gradle via the repo that first downloads the POM and tries to parse it throws errors because naturally ${variable} does not make sense to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the flatten maven plugin which allows you to "compile" values into the POM.